# How can I combine all this into one SQL UPDATE query?

Tags: sql, sqlite, variables, join, sql-update

I'm trying to combine all of this into one query if it's even possible. I'm using SQLLite so I do not have stored procedures available.

The simple version of the query looks like :

`UPDATE FoodIntake SET MealType = 'B' WHERE Time < LunchStrt AND Time > BreakfastStart`

However Time must be derived:

`SET Time = RIGHT(DateTime, 8)`

and LunchStart and BreakfastStart must be brought in from a Patient table based on a parameter being passed from the program. Like so:

```
SELECT LunchStrt FROM Patient WHERE PatientId = :currentPatient AS LunchStrt
SELECT BrkStrt FROM Patient WHERE PatientId = :currentPatient AS BrkStrt
```

I imagine I can at last start by swapping Time for RIGHT(DateTime, 8):

`UPDATE FoodIntake SET MealType = 'B' WHERE RIGHT(DateTime, 8) < LunchStrt AND RIGHT(DateTime, 8) > BreakfastStart`

But I am not sure the proper syntax for bringing in LunchStrt and BrkStrt from the Patient table inside an update if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes:

- SQLite doesn’t have a `RIGHT` function, but you can use the [substr](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) function and pass a negative start position.
- SQLite does support the [BETWEEN ... AND ...](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#between) ternary operator, so you could write `WHERE substr(DateTime, -8) BETWEEN BreakfastStart AND LunchStrt`
- SQLite also supports [scalar subqueries](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#in_op), so you can use those to retrieve the specific values you’re looking for

Combine those three options, and you could write this:

```
UPDATE FoodIntake 
   SET MealType = 'B' 
 WHERE substr(Time, -8) 
        BETWEEN (SELECT BrkStrt FROM Patient WHERE PatientId = :currentPatient)
            AND (SELECT LunchStrt FROM Patient WHERE PatientId = :currentPatient)
```

Comment: wonderful! I just had to change Time to DateTime and it works! I'd recently come under the impression from another article that I would need a CASE statement to do multiple updates but happily that isn't the case.  One quick question.. if I wanted to use BrkStrt elsewhere in a more complicated query, is there some way to set it up as a variable within the query?

Comment: No, SQL doesn't know the concept of a variable.  You can, however, repeat the statement; most SQL parsers will recognize that it's the same value, and re-use the it without running the query twice (SQLite at least does this).